# CGI script's message not rendring in browser?

Tags: perl, file, copy

I'm trying to copy some files from one network share to another using File::Copy.

This is my code:

```
#!C:/strawberry/perl/bin/perl.exe
use File::Copy;
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "<H1>Hello World</H1>\n";
copy("s:\\nl\\cover\\config.jsp", "s:\\temp\\config.jsp") 
    or die "File cannot be copied.";
print "this is not displayed";
```

Why is the 'die' message not rendering?

Comment: If the copy is successful, the message won't be displayed.

Comment: What **is** being displayed? Are you testing this on the command line or via CGI? If the latter, have you looked at your HTTPD's error logs?

Comment: - the copy is not succesful
- the hello world string is being displayed. There is nothing in the httpd log

I've tried this :

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
die "ERROR ";

and "ERROR" isn't displayed either

Comment: That's because die doesn't send to stdout, it sends to stderr.

Comment: Does the script work when you run it from the command line?  If so, the question is about your webserver software and configuration, not perl.

Comment: I don't understand why you are writing a script to copy a file and running it as a CGI program.

Comment: @kinopiko : this is just a part of a larger perl script which has to be run CGI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**If you are running this under a web server (I cannot imagine why, you are sending a `"Content-Type"` header), any error messages you emit using `die` and `warn` will go to the server's error log.**

Further, if you are invoking this as CGI, note that you are lying to the browser by claiming you are sending HTML and not sending HTML.

Especially if you are just learning Perl, you should make an effort to dot all your *i*s and cross all your *t*s:

```
#!C:/strawberry/perl/bin/perl.exe

use strict;   # every time
use warnings; # every time

use CGI qw(:cgi);
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser); # only during debugging

use File::Copy;
use File::Spec::Functions qw(catfile);

$| = 1;

# prefer portable ways of dealing with filenames
# see http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/File::Spec

my $source = catfile(qw(S: n1 cover config.jsp));
my $target = catfile(qw(S: temp config.jsp));

print header('text/plain');

if ( copy $source => $target ) {
    print "'$source' was copied to '$target'\n";
}
else {
    print "'$source' was not copied to '$target'\n";
    # you can use die if you want the error message to
    # go to the error log and an "Internal Server Error"
    # to be shown to the web site visitor.
    # die "'$source' was not copied to '$target'\n";
}
```

See [CGI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/CGI#USING_THE_FUNCTION-ORIENTED_INTERFACE) for the function oriented interface import lists.

Comment: Probably also a good idea to add use Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser); so that messages are sent to the browser.

Comment: thanks sinan, i've tried your code but it gives me an 'internal error'

Comment: @sinan : Premature end of script headers: pub2.pl

Answer (score 4):

Are you sending your stderr to the stdout stream as well? All your prints will got to stdout which is presumably connected to a browser, given your HTML output.

However, `die` writes to the stderr stream. This is likely to go, not to the browser window, but to an error log of some sort. As to where it's going, it depends on what Perl is running within.

One way to check is to `print` something instead of `die`ing in the `or` clause.

So, some questions:

1. How are you running it?
2. If on the command line, show us the exact command.
3. If in a web server of some sort, tell us which one so we can find the logs for you.

Comment: copy("s:\\nl\\cover\\config.jsp", "s:\\temp\\config.jsp") or print "Aarrgghh!";

Comment: die does more than just print a message. It will also exit the script, and perhaps other things. (Return an error code?)

Comment: Try using `use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);` if only for testing purposes

Comment: @Ryan, I wasn't proposing print as a solution, just as a means to find out if my stdout/stderr hypothesis was correct.

Answer (score 3):

`die` sends messages to STDERR, which will wind up in the web server's error logs, not on the screen. There are some CGI modules that offer you greater control over error-handling, or you could install a `$SIG{__DIE__}` handler (if you don't know what that is, then don't worry -- you don't need to), but when I want a quick-and-dirty way to debug my CGI scripts, I put this at the top of the script:

```
    #! /usr/bin/perl
    $src = join'',<DATA>;
    eval $src;
    print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n$@\n" if $@;
    __END__
    ... my cgi script starts here ...
```

This loads the script into a variable, uses `eval` to run the Perl interpreter on that variable's contents, and prints any errors to standard output (the browser window) with a valid header.

Answer (score 0):

```
copy("s:\\nl\\cover\\config.jsp", "s:\\temp\\config.jsp") 
     or die "File cannot be copied.";
print "this is not displayed";
```

Only one of these messages should ever be displayed and it's unclear which you're asking about.

The question *says* you're wondering why the `die` message isn't being displayed; to me, that implies that you're not seeing the message "File cannot be copied." and the most obvious reason for this is that the copy operation is succeeding, but see also the previous responses about looking in the error log if you're running this under CGI.

The text of the messages, though, suggests that you actually mean you're not seeing the message "this is not displayed".  (Why else would you mention that it isn't displayed?)  In that case, the reason you're not seeing it is because `die` causes the program to exit.  After the `copy` fails and the `die` executes, your program is dead.  Terminated.  It has shuffled off this mortal CPU and joined the stack eternal.  It wouldn't `print "this is not displayed"` if you put four million volts through it.  It is an ex-process.

Answer (score 0):

After editing your code, it's apparent that your die is seen as a command and probably needs to be escaped. Note how it is rendered on Stack Overflow in blue (indicating that it is a keyword). Try switching to a synonym like `"shutdown"` instead.